# Best image format for markdown page for github or bitbucket?

Tags: github, bitbucket, markdown

What is the best image format (e.g. png, jpg) for images to be displayed in a Markdown page on public git repositories like github or bitbucket? in terms of size, speed, and compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Both png and jpg are commonly used. It depends mainly on what kind of image you have and the way it is exported.

If you need transparency, you can use png. If you need a very high contrast picture with many colors, you might consider using jpg instead.